# how to replicate this motion blur effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I am wondering how to replicate the motion blur effect seen in the image below.

[image]

I have tried a variety of approaches: motion blurring the intended word, adding noise and using gradients in layer masks, etc, but all to no avail. I am unsure what to try next. I think my last port of call is going to be trying a gradient map with each colour (pink, purple, red, orange, yellow) being represented somewhere along the black-white continuum. Then, using a soft brush, I could manually paint the blur for each respective colour. But I am unsure if this is going to work and would prefer to enlist some advice before going down this road.

Any thoughts or recommendations are fully welcomed. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm experimenting with this right now, but don't have much luck. The image is very digitally eroded so it's not clear what is going on. The effect seems to be achievable by somehow manipulating the channels separately.

Comment: I am not sure why I overlooked separating the colour channels, as I have already done so in the design to date. I guess the diversity of the colour (as mentioned) directed me towards a sort of gradient mapping.. but I think this is wrong and colour channel separation is the likely culprit here. 

Thanks to you and @Rafael for the help, it is super appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is called a "video glitch", more specifically some color offset. Probably you can find some pre-made filter looking for "video Glitch"

(I have not tested it yet) I say that you need to

1. Separate a copy of the file
2. Apply a different amount of motion blur to each channel incrementally, let's say 5px for the R 10 for the G 15 for the B.
3. Apply the reassembled RGB file on top of the original with a blend mode.

Probably you need to apply the same amount of motion blur but offset it for each channel.

I will make some tests later :o)

---

If we use the logic of the gitch, probably you need to separate the file in YUV channels. But I'm not sure if that is possible on Ps. Probably it can be done in Lab, applying **the blur** and **the offset** on the color channels a+b.